# Quantization of $x$ and $p$ through the Weyl transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, phase-space, deformation-quantization

I have a question about the development of the integral for calculating the quantization of the classical variables $x$ and $p$ using the Weyl transformation method. The notation that the textbook I'm using is  $Op(A) =\hat{A}$. I'm trying to calculate the quantization of the function $A = q^{i}.$ In order to show that $$Op(q^{i})u = q^{i}u.$$ I am following the following step by step lecture notes from author Yufan Ge, example 1 on page 7. (The Weyl Quantization: a brief introduction - [https://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~aricif2/ncgSem/Yufan_Ge_Weyl_Quantization.pdf](https://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Earicif2/ncgSem/Yufan_Ge_Weyl_Quantization.pdf) - ). Here is the calculation procedure:

$$Op[a(p,q)]u = \frac{1}{2\pi\hslash}\int e^{\frac{ip}{\hslash}(q-q')}a\Big(\frac{q+q'}{2},p\Big)u(q')dpdq'$$

For $a(p,q) = q^{i}$, we have:

$$Op[q^{i}]u = \frac{1}{2\pi\hslash}\int e^{\frac{ip}{\hslash}(q-q')}\Big(\frac{q+q^{i}{'}}{2}\Big)u(q')dpdq' \\
=\frac{1}{2\pi\hslash}\int e^{\frac{ipq}{\hslash}}\Big(\int e^{\frac{-ipq'}{\hslash}}\frac{q^{i}{'}}{2}u(q')dq'\Big)+\frac{1}{2\pi\hslash}\int e^{\frac{ipq}{\hslash}}\Big(\int e^{\frac{-ipq'}{\hslash}}\frac{q^{i}}{2}u(q')dq'\Big)dp\\
=\frac{1}{2\pi\hslash}\int e^{\frac{ipq}{\hslash}}F'\Big[\frac{p^{i}}{2}u(p)\Big]dp+q^{i}\frac{1}{2\pi\hslash}\int e^{\frac{ipq}{\hslash}}F'\Big[u(p)\Big]dq'\\
=q^{i}u.$$

My question consists of the last two lines. I think the author made a mistake in the development. Or I'm missing something. I would like to understand this step by step correctly. My other question is about the quantization of the momentum variable p. In these class notes the author says that by carrying out the same procedure it is possible to show that we will arrive at:

$$Op[p_{i}]u = -i\hslash\frac{\partial u}{\partial q^{i}}.$$

I also tried to show this, but I couldn't. If anyone can show me the step-by-step process for these two examples or knows of a book that does these calculations properly, it would help me a lot. I learn very well when I see solved examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr; your exposition suffers from attempts at spurious generality and evil notation, leading to mistakes; in particular, it is best to clump the differentials after the integral sign, so you don't forget them, as he did!

You can be much more direct:
$$Op[q]u = \frac{1}{2\pi\hslash}\int \!~\!dpdq'~~e^{\frac{ip}{\hslash}(q-q')}\Big(\frac{q+q^{i}{'}}{2}\Big)u(q') \\
= \int \!\! dq'~~\delta (q-q')\Big(\frac{q+q^{i}{'}}{2}\Big)u(q')=q u(q).$$

Likewise,
$$Op[p]u = \frac{1}{2\pi\hslash}\int \!~\!dpdq'~~e^{\frac{ip}{\hslash}(q-q')} p ~u(q') \\
= \int \!\! dq'~~(-i\hbar\partial_q )\delta (q-q') ~~ u(q')=-i\hbar\partial_q u(q).$$

You may expand Fourier transforms and inverses, but that's wild overkill that suggests the author of the notes lacked the time to make his sloppy/complacent/careless  digest of an undisclosed text shorter. (He's skipped a *dp* and conflated the Fourier transform with its derivative... I won't bother fixing them for you, once you see the point made above.)

Personally, I am partial in favor of our [booklet](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf), instead, but it is not as (haplessly) detailed as the notes you are reading. It assumes dexterity with δ-functions and their properties. Your fundamental Weyl map equation (5) here is an obvious rewriting of (140) in it, but, there, everything is all but a tautology.

---

*"Je n'ai fait celle-ci plus longue que parce que je n'ai pas eu le loisir de la faire plus courte."*
Blaise Pascal, Les provinciales (1656), XVI